# Go easy on the onion or onions

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct to say, "Go easy on the onion" or "Go easy on the onions" when you order at a fast-food restaurant?

Comment: The first (I would think); I cannot think of a single fast food dish where you would receive more than a single onion. If the onion is diced (like on a hot dog), then I would still use the singular (as I just did).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not necessarily. *Onion* works in all cases.

Comment: @Kris Glad we sorted that out, and we can't go to Chili's and order two awesome blossoms (because they discontinued it). But that would be multiple onions (and terrible for us).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch would you say "go easy on the tomato" or "tomatoes" if you were ordering a mixed salad?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hold the tomato. Even for cherry tomatoes. Whiskey on the rocks. Easy on the ice. But is it ***universally*** singular? Want to go get some nachos? Hold the jalapeños?